# Difference between nlapiScheduleScript() and nlapiYieldScript()

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

What is the difference between `nlapiScheduleScript()` and `nlapiYieldScript()` and which one will prefer to reset governance points and in which scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

nlapiScheduleScript puts an instance of the scheduled script into the queue for scheduled scripts.  nlapiYieldScript is the api for pausing your scheduled script long enough for governance limits to reset.

You can use both the difference being that if you use nlapiYieldScript you do not need to keep track of where you stopped or "reset" you script.  If you use nlapiScheduleScript, you will need to keep track what record or line you are currently working on and pass them as parameter values in the nlapiScheduleScript call.

Comment: Thanks Rusty, Can you Please more elaborate, In which API(nlapiScheduleScript() or nlapiYieldscript())we use nlapiSetRecoveryPoint() to reset governance points.is it recommended to use recovery point to reschedule the the script because it consumes high governance points.